# trouble converting UTC date to M/D/YYYY with date.js

Tags: utc, datejs

I am trying to convert a UTC date that currently looks like `<span class="enrolldate">2011-10-01 22:00:00</span>`

simply to a M/D/YYYY date format with date.js.  Can someone help?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the [API](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation) for date.js, you can output the format you require with:

```
Date.today().toString("M/d/yyyy"); // 11/19/2007
```